# Fetch/take data from a child element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It looks like it is easy, but I can't find any information...

I have this parent component:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import Input from "./form/Input";
import { useNavigate, useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

const Login =() => {

    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password,setPassword] = useState("");
    const {setJwtToken} = useOutletContext("");
    const {setAlertClassName} = useOutletContext("");
    const {setAlertMessage} = useOutletContext("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();


    const handleSubmit=(event)=>{

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("email/password",email,password);

        let payload ={
            email: email,
            password: password,
        }

        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }

        fetch(`/authenticate`,requestOptions)
        .then((request)=> request.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if(data.error) {
                setAlertClassName("alert-danger");
                setAlertMessage(data.message);
            } else {
                setJwtToken(data.access_token);
                setAlertClassName("d-none");
                setAlertMessage("");
                navigate("/");

            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setAlertClassName("alert-danger");
            setAlertMessage(error);
        })

    }

    return (

        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <hr/>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Input
                    title="Email Address"
                    type="email"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="email"
                    autoComplete="email-new"

                    value="admin@example.com"
                />
                <Input
                    title="Password"
                    type="password"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="password"
                    autoComplete="password-new"

                    value="secret"
                />
                <Input
                    type="submit"
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    value="Login"
                />
            </form>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Login
```

And the child component:

```
import { forwardRef } from "react"

const Input = forwardRef((props,ref)=> {
    return(
        <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor={props.name} className="form-lable">
                {props.title}
            </label>
            <input
                type={props.type}
                className={props.className}
                id={props.id}
                ref={ref}
                name={props.name}
                placeholder={props.placeHolder}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
                value={props.value}
            />

            <div className={props.errorDiv}>{props.errorMsg}</div>

        </div>

    )
})

export default Input;
```

i like to fetch the value of both "Email Address" input and "Password" input
and set them using setEmail and setPassowrd,
but how the hell am I taking it from the value of the child inputs?

I removed the onChange. The hardcoded values are for testing, but it got me wonder how to fetch the values.

Comment: Did you try to use a `onInput` instead of `onChange` ?

Comment: If you console.log `payload` before fetching, are the values correctly set ?

Comment: "setPassowrd" can't be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are the values are hardcoded in the parent?

You should pass the value from the `useState`. For example, for the email input, it would be:

```
<Input [...] value={email} />
```

If you want to set a default value you can do it like this:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("admin@example.com");
```

Comment: its for quick testing to not enter the values each time
updated the question

Comment: Answers aren't the right place for questions (even if rhetorical). That is what comments to the question is for. [Stack Overflow is *** *** ***not*** *** *** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).